# How to create/ test client side python applications in cloud 9 IDE

Tags: python, client-side, cloud9-ide

I have been getting into programming and I would love it if my friends and I could program python (Client Side as in I could run it on my computer offline(Saying it is an offline application)) in cloud 9 IDE (If you don't know you can work real time with your team in the IDE).  The problem is it will run it as if I am using it as a web language.  Also DJANGO just gets in the way.
Any way I can launch it as an application?

Comment: Could you please tell us some more to help us pinpoint the issue?
- What steps did you take? 
- Did you get any error messages? 
- Do you see any errors in the browser's JS console? 
- Is it reproducible? On which browsers? And in incognito mode?

Answer (score -1):

You need not install Django on Cloud9. You've got the option to install a blank container. From there you can pip install anything like. Write your .py file and then python run myfile.py -- [Link to Cloud9 Docs](https://docs.c9.io/docs/writing-a-python-app)

While not as slick as Cloud9 [Python Anywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which is more focussed on Python Apps.